# How can I use SumProduct Function in SSRS?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have three columns in a SSRS table which record telephony data

Row 1 is Calls Offered which is a straight count
Row 2 is Calls Answered is as above
Row 3 is a Service Level Percentage of Calls Answered/Calls Offered

This table spans for 9 months and then there is a total column at the end
Row 1 and Row 2 are easy enough because it's just a grand total but for Row 3
I need to do a weighted average for all the percentages across the 9 months

So how can I do a SUMPRODUCT which will give me the weighted average service level over 9 months

In Excel my formula is as follows: =SUMPRODUCT(E10:M10,E$8:M$8)/SUM(E$8:M$8)

So Row 8 is my calls offered and Row 10 being my percentages - how do I replicate this in SSRS?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out if anyone is interested it was

=(Sum(Fields!Calls_Answered.Value)/Sum(Fields!Calls_Offered.Value)) * Sum(Fields!Calls_Offered.Value)/Sum(Fields!Calls_Offered.Value)

So it has to do the calculation of the service level percentage first then times that against the amount of calls offered and then divide it against the amount of Calls Offered

Thanks
Dan