# SSRS Help within Verint v15 WFM

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

I work in the planning function for a contact centre and we've recently updated our WFM (Verint 11 to Verint 15) and previously used Cognos which has now been replaced with SSRS. The problem I'm having is I'm trying to create an Ad Hoc report which will give the Daily Call Volume, Grade of Service and AHT. The report runs at an interval level and sums volumes at a daily level no problem, but the Grade of Service simply sums each interval as well rather than an aggregate view, has anyone else managed to solve this?

I've tried writing a sumproduct function, I've tried runningvalue but nothing works so far. I know the correct GoS for the day is 40, but getting this from SSRS is proving a challenge

Comment: How do you calculate your GoS for the day as 40?

Comment: A sumproduct(forecast cv:forecast pca)/total forecast cv. That matches what Pulse shows as well in WFM

Comment: does this help: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999008/how-can-i-use-sumproduct-function-in-ssrs